# Create a simple question and answer in R markdown

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create an interactive document where students can input their answers to the homework problems.

```
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float:
      collapsed: true
      smooth_scroll: false
    toc_depth: 4
    theme: yeti 
    highlight: tango
runtime: shiny
```

I want to have a simple question "Input all possible rupture paths."
The correct answers would be `c("ABEF","ABCDG","ABCDEF","ABDEF")`
I want student to be able to submit as many submissions till getting all four correct answers.

I am very new to shiny and this is my attempt of just starting it.

````
```{r letter-a, echo=FALSE}
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput('answer', label = 'Input all possible rupture paths', width = '30%'),
  actionButton("go", "Submit!"),
  uiOutput('feedback')
)

shinyUI(UI)
```
````

This runs and creates a box, I don't know how to define the correct answer and compare the submitted answer to the correct ones.

[image]

Thank you!! Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `learnr`. It will save you a lot of time and hassle.

To answer your question, it would be helpful to create an interactive document which looks like Shiny. To do this, you will simply have to create an Rmd file. Just save the file with .Rmd extension.

Based on your question, I tried to recreate the scenario with this code. Before you run this:

1. Make sure you have installed `learnr` by using `install.packages("learnr")`.
2. Load it using `library(learnr)`
3. Copy this code and save it as an Rmd file. Or you can start a new document through File -> New File -> R Markdown -> From Template -> Interactive Tutorial -> OK

   ````
   ---
   title: "Tutorial"
   output: learnr::tutorial
   runtime: shiny_prerendered
   ---

   ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
   library(learnr)
   knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
   ``` #
   ````

   ````
       ```{r options, echo = FALSE} 
       question(
         "Input all possible rupture paths",
         answer("ABC"),
         answer("ABCD"),
         answer("ABEF, ABCDG, ABCDEF, ABDEF", correct = TRUE, message = "Correct Answer!"),
         type = "learnr_text", # radio
         try_again = "Wrong Answer, please try again",
         message = "Remember to enter answer in this format seperated by commas: ABC, ABCD",
         submit_button = "Submit",
         try_again_button = "Try Again",
         allow_retry = TRUE,
         options = list(
           placeholder = "Enter answer in this format seperated by commas: ABC, ABCD",
           trim = TRUE
         )
       )
   ````

[image]

To learn more, this will help you get started: https://rstudio.github.io/learnr/#Getting_Started.

Here's some sample code from here: https://rstudio.github.io/learnr/questions.html

````
       
        ```{r letter-a, echo=FALSE}
        question("What number is the letter A in the English alphabet?",
          answer("8"),
          answer("14"),
          answer("1", correct = TRUE),
          answer("23")
        )
        ```
````

[image]

You can also allow students to keep trying using  `allow_retry = TRUE`

**Update:**

You can add the following lines in the question function.

```
question(
      "Input all possible rupture paths",
      answer("ABC"),
      answer("ABCD"),
      answer("ABEF, ABCDG, ABCDEF, ABDEF", correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABCDEF, ABCDG, ABDEF, ABEF', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABCDEF, ABCDG, ABEF, ABDEF', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABCDEF, ABDEF, ABCDG, ABEF', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABCDEF, ABDEF, ABEF, ABCDG', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABCDEF, ABEF, ABCDG, ABDEF', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABCDEF, ABEF, ABDEF, ABCDG', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABCDG, ABCDEF, ABDEF, ABEF', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABCDG, ABCDEF, ABEF, ABDEF', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABCDG, ABDEF, ABCDEF, ABEF', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABCDG, ABDEF, ABEF, ABCDEF', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABCDG, ABEF, ABCDEF, ABDEF', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABCDG, ABEF, ABDEF, ABCDEF', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABDEF, ABCDEF, ABCDG, ABEF', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABDEF, ABCDEF, ABEF, ABCDG', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABDEF, ABCDG, ABCDEF, ABEF', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABDEF, ABCDG, ABEF, ABCDEF', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABDEF, ABEF, ABCDEF, ABCDG', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABDEF, ABEF, ABCDG, ABCDEF', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABEF, ABCDEF, ABCDG, ABDEF', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABEF, ABCDEF, ABDEF, ABCDG', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABEF, ABCDG, ABCDEF, ABDEF', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABEF, ABCDG, ABDEF, ABCDEF', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABEF, ABDEF, ABCDEF, ABCDG', correct = TRUE),
      answer('ABEF, ABDEF, ABCDG, ABCDEF', correct = TRUE),
      type = "learnr_text", # radio
      try_again = "Wrong Answer, please try again",
      message = "Remember to enter answer in this format seperated by commas: ABC, ABCD",
      submit_button = "Submit",
      try_again_button = "Try Again",
      allow_retry = TRUE,
      options = list(
        placeholder = "Enter answer in this format seperated by commas: ABC, ABCD",
        trim = TRUE
      )
    )
```

To generate this, I did the following. I'm sure there is a better way to do this by converting this into a function. Here's what I was able to do for now.

```
a <- data.frame(gtools::permutations(4, 4, c("ABEF","ABCDG","ABCDEF","ABDEF")))
b <- paste(a$X1, a$X2, a$X3, a$X4, sep = ", ")
c <- paste("'", b, "'", sep = "")
d <- paste(c , "correct = TRUE)",sep = ", ")
e <- paste0( "answer(", d)
e
```

Running this will give this, which you can then paste in the question function:

```
[1] "answer('ABCDEF, ABCDG, ABDEF, ABEF', correct = TRUE)"
 [2] "answer('ABCDEF, ABCDG, ABEF, ABDEF', correct = TRUE)"
 [3] "answer('ABCDEF, ABDEF, ABCDG, ABEF', correct = TRUE)"
 [4] "answer('ABCDEF, ABDEF, ABEF, ABCDG', correct = TRUE)"
 [5] "answer('ABCDEF, ABEF, ABCDG, ABDEF', correct = TRUE)"
 [6] "answer('ABCDEF, ABEF, ABDEF, ABCDG', correct = TRUE)"
 [7] "answer('ABCDG, ABCDEF, ABDEF, ABEF', correct = TRUE)"
 [8] "answer('ABCDG, ABCDEF, ABEF, ABDEF', correct = TRUE)"
 [9] "answer('ABCDG, ABDEF, ABCDEF, ABEF', correct = TRUE)"
[10] "answer('ABCDG, ABDEF, ABEF, ABCDEF', correct = TRUE)"
[11] "answer('ABCDG, ABEF, ABCDEF, ABDEF', correct = TRUE)"
[12] "answer('ABCDG, ABEF, ABDEF, ABCDEF', correct = TRUE)"
[13] "answer('ABDEF, ABCDEF, ABCDG, ABEF', correct = TRUE)"
[14] "answer('ABDEF, ABCDEF, ABEF, ABCDG', correct = TRUE)"
[15] "answer('ABDEF, ABCDG, ABCDEF, ABEF', correct = TRUE)"
[16] "answer('ABDEF, ABCDG, ABEF, ABCDEF', correct = TRUE)"
[17] "answer('ABDEF, ABEF, ABCDEF, ABCDG', correct = TRUE)"
[18] "answer('ABDEF, ABEF, ABCDG, ABCDEF', correct = TRUE)"
[19] "answer('ABEF, ABCDEF, ABCDG, ABDEF', correct = TRUE)"
[20] "answer('ABEF, ABCDEF, ABDEF, ABCDG', correct = TRUE)"
[21] "answer('ABEF, ABCDG, ABCDEF, ABDEF', correct = TRUE)"
[22] "answer('ABEF, ABCDG, ABDEF, ABCDEF', correct = TRUE)"
[23] "answer('ABEF, ABDEF, ABCDEF, ABCDG', correct = TRUE)"
[24] "answer('ABEF, ABDEF, ABCDG, ABCDEF', correct = TRUE)"
```

There is definitely a better way to do this. Try posting a new question and I'm sure the `learnr` community will help.

Comment: Thank you this is great and I have been looking at the learnr package and its perfect for what I want. I cannot find a simple way to have it accept multiple different answers defined by a function. For example, here I would want it to accept all 24 permutations of different orders they could enter the 4 answers. I would like to use something like: `permutations(4, 4, c("ABEF","ABCDG","ABCDEF","ABDEF"))`. How can I do this?

Comment: Which package is the ```permutations``` function from?

Comment: I'm sure there is a more straightforward way to do it than my now proposed solution. Please see update

Answer (score 2):

You cant try following code snippet. Edit it as per you requirements.

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    textInput('answer', label = 'Input all possible rupture paths', width = '30%'),
    actionButton("go", "Submit!"),
    uiOutput('feedback')
  ),
  
  server <- function(input,output,session){
    answers=reactiveVal(c("ABEF","ABCDG","ABCDEF","ABDEF"))
    
    observeEvent(input$go,{
      req(input$answer)
      if(input$answer %in% answers()){
        answers(setdiff(answers(),input$answer))
        output$feedback=renderText(paste("Correct answer.",length(answers()),"to go!"))
      }else{
        output$feedback=renderText(paste("Incorrect answer.",length(answers()),"to go!"))
      }
    })
  }
)
```

[image: example 1]

[image]